# Reformulando URL no htacess

Tags: htaccess, url-rewrite

To tentando reformular a url que faz com que mude a pagina. Tenho a seguinte *URL*

`www.site.com/categoria.php?cat=Humor&page=3`

Da forma cita acima a paginação funciona perfeitamente. Porém que melhorar a url com o htacess. Gostaria que ficasse assim:

`www.site.com/Humor/3`

A parte do `www.site.com/Humor/` já fiz, só nao tenho noção de como eu fazer com que a paginação funcione.

No meu htacess a configuração está assim
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ categoria.php?cat=$1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou escrever alguns exemplos para ver se te ajudo...

**Exemplo com 1 querystring**

No caso da URL **www.domain.com/pagina-x**, será interpretada como **www.domain.com/index_.php?pagename=pagina-x**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index_.php?pagename=$1
```

Explicação:

- `RewriteEngine On` -> Ativa o suporte à reescrita
- `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f` -> Não aplica a condição para arquivos
- `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d` -> Não aplica a condição para diretórios
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index_.php?pagename=$1` -> Regra de reescrita onde qualquer string (.*) após a pasta, onde estiver o .htaccess, será interpretado por *index.php* passado na variável *pagename*

---

**Exemplo com 2 querystring** (Ex.: idioma + página)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ site.php?lang=$1&pagename=$2
```

Link user request -> **www.domain.com/pt/produtos**

Server-side -> **www.domain.com/site.php?lang=pt&pagename=produtos**

---

**Exemplo com 2 querystring** (Ex.: página + subpágina)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2
```

Link user request -> **www.domain.com/page_X/subpage_Y**

Server-side -> **www.domain.com/index.php?page=page_X&subpage=subpage_Y**